# a continuous analog for adjusted mutual information

Tags: clustering, mutual-information, partitioning

I'm interested in comparing a set of electoral redistricting plans to, which can be conceived as partitions of an area.

A measure like mutual information looks attractive.

Let $U_i$ be a district from plan $U$ and $V_i$ be a district from plan $U$. Let $a$ be the area of polygon, and $A$ be the area of the entire city to be districted.

$$
\text{MI}(U, V) = \sum_{i=1}^{|U|} \sum_{j=1}^{|V|} \frac{a(U_i \cap V_j)}{A}\log\left(\frac{A * a(U_i \cap V_j)}{a(U_i)*a(V_j)}\right)
$$

So that's all great. But, it would be really wonderful to use a measure like [adjusted mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjusted_mutual_information).

However, I've only ever been able to see the expected mutual information defined using a hypergeometric distribution which assumes that the elements contained in a partition are discrete.

I can certainly use the discrete approach to approximate a continuous expected Mutual Information, but has anyone worked out continuous version of AMI?